# QtCreator tricky project

Tags: qt, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions

I have a project in `Qt Creator` which has several shared library projects and the main project which also contains the main function. What I want is to add a new project which shouldn't be a shared library but just a project with some header files where I keep definitions and error codes. What I wish is to be able to add the path of this project to other projects `INCLUDEPATH` in order to use those files in other projects.

To do so I created an empty project which `.pro` file looks like this:

```
HEADERS += \
    myHeader.h
```

but when I build the whole project it complains that it doesn't find the main in this project with only one header.

Is it possible in `QtCreator` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.pri` file which has your `INCLUDEPATH`, etc; and then refer to it in your other projects' `.pro` files:

```
# Common.pri
INCLUDEPATH += ../myPath
INCLUDE += myHeader.h

# OtherProject.pro
!include( ./Common.pri ) {
    error( Could not find the Common.pri file. )
}

INCLUDEPATH += ../myOtherPath
```

Remember to use the `+=` operator in your `.pro` files otherwise they will overwrite the `.pri` file variables.